# delegate doesn't get parameter

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm trying to find a MenuTreeItem in my list of MenuTreeItems that is of the type Category and possesses a supplied categoryID.

Unfortunately, I get an error message:

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'mti' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I use Visual Studio 2008 and C# and the .Net Framework 3.5.

```
int mtiIndex = menuTreeItems.FindIndex(delegate (MenuTreeItem mti) {
                    return (typeof(mti) == dummyCat.GetType()) && (mti.id == menuTreeItems[i].categoryID);
               });
```

Comment: Why not create a regular method?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895552/parse-datatype-in-c-sharp/6895583#6895583

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you either want `mti.GetType()` or `typeof(MenuTreeItem)`

Answer (score 2):

```
int mtiIndex = menuTreeItems.FindIndex((MenuTreeItem mti) =>
  {return (mti.GetType() == dummyCat.GetType()) && (mti.id == menuTreeItems[i].categoryID);});
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to call GetType() on mti I think. Like this:

```
mtiIndex = menuTreeItems.FindIndex(delegate (MenuTreeItem mti){ 
    return (mti.GetType() == dummyCat.GetType()) && 
      (mti.id == menuTreeItems[i].categoryID);  
  });
```